# sql query for Last 5 years and group by?

Tags: sql, group-by, db2, sum

I'm new to SQL, I'm working on DB2, I need to get the sum of x and y of the last 5 years for a id.

the following is the query up to which i've acheived so far, but, i need to get only the last 5 yaers, this gets me the data for all the years. I've tried to add top 5 for the sql statement, it seems to not work, it shows some error. How do I modify this query to fetch only the last 5 years data?

```
select (sum(X) + sum(Y)) as tot,some_date
from table where fkid = 1 
group by year order by year desc;
```

The following the data format that I'm expecting.

Total           Year
552,074.78  2012-01-01
466,283.62  2011-01-01
640,813.37  2010-01-01
721,182.28  2009-01-01
719,676.05  2008-01-01

The error that i'm getting is as follows

> Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=5;VALUE ( CONCAT || / - +                      FROM INTO * , \ AS . YEAR, DRIVER=3.58.81
>   SQLState:  42601 ErrorCode: -104
>   Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=SQL_CURLH200C1, DRIVER=3.58.81
>   SQLState:  26501
>   ErrorCode: -514

Edit: the column has date type in it, and the column name is not year, for example sake i've modified it to have some_year.

Comment: If it shows **some** error, you'll need to do **something** to fix your query, obviously. Begin by stating your DB2 platform and version. Also include with your query sample data and the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query is easy (assuming this is the only problem).  `year` is a reserved word, so surround it by double quotes:

```
select (sum(X) + sum(Y)) as tot, "year"
from table
where fkid = 1 
group by "year"
order by "year" desc;
```

Getting the last five years is a different matter.  Based on the `year` column, you could do:

```
select (sum(X) + sum(Y)) as tot, "year"
from table
where fkid = 1 and year >= year(current timestamp) - 5
group by "year"
order by "year" desc;
```

Or you might actually have another column that has a date time that you can use instead of `"year"`.

EDIT:

If you have a column called `dt` that is the date, you would use:

```
select (sum(X) + sum(Y)) as tot, year(dt) as "year"
from table
where fkid = 1 and dt >= CURRENT DATE - 5 years and dt <= CURRENT DATE
group by year(dt)
order by year(dt) desc;
```

If you want only one row with the sum, leave out the `group by` clause.

Comment: Never mind, i've figured it. Thanks. A little searching helped.

Comment: >select (sum(X) + sum(Y)) as tot, some_year
from table
where fkid = 1 and year(some_year) >= year(current timestamp) - 5
group by some_year
order by some_year desc;